# Problems with Java Triangle Type Program

Tags: java, types, geometry

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class labAssignment4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables
        double a, b, c;

        System.out.println("Enter longest side: ");
        a = user.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter second side: ");
        b = user.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter third side: ");
        c = user.nextDouble();
        //Help fix code to compute triangle type correctly...

                if (a==b&&b==c)
                {
                    System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
                }

                else if (a==b && b==c);
                    {
                        System.out.println("Isoceles Triangle");
                    }
                    if (!((a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c))); 
                    {
                    System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
                    }
                    if (((a + b) >= (c)) ||((a + b) >= (b)) ||((b +c) >= (a)));
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
                    }



          } 
    }
```

Help correct formula to compute correct triangle type....any help would be appreciated.
I need some help modifying this code and it seems like it keeps giving me an error returning more than one result. As a result I receive that my values are equal to an isoceles, scalene, and not a triangle values at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem is that you have a semicolon after the else statement:

```
 else if (a==b && b==c);//<-- semicolon here
```

Thus you will always print `"Isoceles Triangle"

Also, you have semicolons after the next two `if` statements:

```
if (!((a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c))); //<-- semicolon here
{
   System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
}
if (((a + b) >= (c)) ||((a + b) >= (b)) ||((b +c) >= (a))); //<-- semicolon here
{
   System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
}
```

These will cause your program to print `"Scalene Triangle"` and `"Not a Triangle"` regardless of whether or not the test conditions in your `if` statement are true/false.

The fix is simple: remove the semicolons!

Comment: Thanks that fixes one of the problems

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are a bit messed up. Need to fix up the brackets on that else, and remove semicolons too. And the conditions for being a triangle need fixing as well.

```
if (a==b && b==c) System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
    else {
    if ((a==b && b!=c) || (a==c && a!=b)) {
       System.out.println("Isoceles Triangle");
       }
    if (a!=b && b!=c && a!=c) {
       System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
       }
    if !(((a + b) > c) && ((a + c) > b) && ((b + c) > a)) {
       System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
       }
    }
```